# Is there a better way to add user to object / array

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am creating an android app that connects to my node.js server which is using socket.io.

Now I'm not having any issues, but I feel like there is a better way to do this. The code below adds the user to the `userPool` variable based on the user's location country/state/city.

```
var userPool = {};

// Adds the user to the pool object
socket.on('add or update user to pool', function(data) {
  if (userPool.hasOwnProperty(data['country'])) {
    if (userPool[data['country']].hasOwnProperty(data['state'])) {
      if (userPool[data['country']][data['state']].hasOwnProperty(data['city'])) {
        if (userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']].hasOwnProperty(data['user_type'])) {
          userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']][data['user_type']][socket.id] = data;
        }
        else {
          userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']][data['user_type']] = {};
          userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']][data['user_type']][socket.id] = data;
        }
      }
      else {
        userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']] = {};
        userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']][data['user_type']] = {};
        userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']][data['user_type']][socket.id] = data;
      }
    }
    else {
      userPool[data['country']][data['state']] = {};
      userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']] = {};
      userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']][data['user_type']] = {};
      userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']][data['user_type']][socket.id] = data;
    }
  }
  else {
    userPool[data['country']] = {};
    userPool[data['country']][data['state']] = {};
    userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']] = {};
    userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']][data['user_type']] = {};
    userPool[data['country']][data['state']][data['city']][data['user_type']][socket.id] = data;
  }

  if (!socket.hasOwnProperty('userInfo'))
    socket['userInfo'] = { 'country': data['country'], 'state': data['state'], 'city': data['city'], 'user_type': data['user_type'] };

});
```

Comment: A little hard to follow, but I'm noticing a lot of code repetition.  As much as you can, try not to repeat yourself.

Comment: Shouldn’t this be asked on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about something like this:

```
let userPool = {};

socket.on('add or update user to pool', addUserToPool);

function addUserToPool (data) {
    let country     = data['country']
        , state     = data['state']
        , city      = data['city']
        , user_type = data['user_type'];

    userPool[country] = userPool[country] || {};
    userPool[country][city] = userPool[country][city] || {};
    userPool[country][city][user_type] = userPool[country][city][user_type] || {};

    let userTypes = userPool[country][city][user_type];

    userTypes[socket.id] = data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately there are libraries to take care of this grunt work for you. If I'm following your logic correctly:

```
import extend from 'deep-extend';

socket.on('add or update user to pool', (data) => {
  userPool = extend(userPool, {
    [data.country]: {
      [data.state]: {
        [data.city]: {
          [data.user_type]: {
            [socket.id]: data
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```